# How do compilers handle enums with more complex values?

Tags: c, rust, enums, record

I had this explained to me once, but I am hazy on the details: so when you have an enum, say, in C, where the enums have no starting value, like so:

```
enum Level {  
LOW,   
MEDIUM,   
HIGH 
};
```

The compiler just assigns arbitrary integer values to these guys. Even if you were to specify the integers explicitly:

```
enum Level {  
LOW = 0,
MEDIUM = 1,   
HIGH = 2 
};
```

Now you're just doing what the compiler might have done anyways, but explicitly.

But what about more complicated enums, such as those found in Java or Rust? E.g. from the enums section of the Rust book:

```
enum IpAddr {
        V4(u8, u8, u8, u8),
        V6(String),
    }
```

When it was explained to me a long time ago, I vaguely remember there being mentioned that this is handled via using 2 structs, something like:

```
struct enums {

    0,  //arbitrary value used for V4

    1   //arbitrary value used for V6

}
struct values {

     u8 array[4],

     char * string

}
```

Where the arbitrary values of the first struct somehow map onto the values that they can store. I also remember that the person who explained it to me called these kind of enums some term that had the word "record" in it. I cannot find any mention of this technique anywhere on this website or otherwise, so I would appreciate if someone could either explain it or at least tell me what topic to research on my own.

Comment: You want an explanation of *what*? You seem to have understood it already: "where the arbitrary values of the first struct somehow map onto the values that they can store."

Comment: Search for "tagged unions".

Comment: Tagged unions, yes, that was it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, the closest equivalent would be along the lines of:

```c
typedef enum {
  TAG_V4,
  TAG_V6,
} ip_addr_tag;

typedef struct {
  a: unsigned char;
  b: unsigned char;
  c: unsigned char;
  d: unsigned char;
} ip_addr_v4;

typedef struct {
  char* string
} ip_addr_v6;

typedef union {
  ip_addr_v4 v4;
  ip_addr_v6 v6;
} ip_addr_content;

// if `tag == TAG_V4`, you may use `content.v4`
// if `tag == TAG_V6`, you may use `content.v6`
typedef struct {  // implement a tagged union
  ip_addr_tag tag;
  ip_addr_content content;
} ip_addr;
```

There are a few differences:

- Rust is smart about tags, e.g. if it finds a byte that's unused in the union, it's going to use that byte to store the tag instead of needing one more byte to store it;
- Rust's type system guarantees that you use the tag/union correctly;
- Rust ensures that destructors are run when you leave the scope.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
enum IpAddr {
    V4(u8, u8, u8, u8),
    V6(String),
}
```

Can roughly be thought of as:

```
enum IpAddrDiscriminant {
    DiscriminantForV4 = 0,
    DiscriminantForV6 = 1,
}
union IpAddrPayload {
    fourints: (u8, u8, u8, u8),
    string: String,
}
struct IpAddrInternalRepresentation {
    discriminant: IpAddrDiscriminant,
    payload: IpAddrPayload,
}
```

In the internal representation, `IpAddrDiscriminant` simply encodes whether your enum value is an IP4 or IP6 value, but does not associate a value itself.

Instead, the internal representation stores a [`union`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/unions.html). A `union` is an area of memory that can hold - in this case - either a `(u8, u8, u8, u8)` or a `String`. It consumes as much memory as the largest of its variants (modulo padding and possibly other technicalities). The `union` itself does not know if it currently contains a tuple of `u8` or a `String` - but `IpAddrInternalrepresentation` always accesses `payload` in accordance with `discriminant`, i.e. the `discriminant` tells which of the variants is currently contained in the `payload`.

You could theoretically also hand-code your `IpAddrInternalRepresentation` and set/retrieve the files (probably using `unsafe` rust), but having the compiler do it frees you from having to deal with all the (unsafe) boilerplate.

See also https://patshaughnessy.net/2018/3/15/how-rust-implements-tagged-unions.

Answer (score 0):

*"...where the enums have no starting value,.... The compiler just assigns arbitrary integer values...."* This is wrong; if an enumeration declaration starts with no `=` definitions the enumeration constants start at 0 and one is added to each subsequent enumeration constant unless a `=` definition is encountered.

You can achieve something like the `enum IpAddr` example in C by creating a tagged union. Here is one way to do this pretty concisely using a struct to contain an enum and an anonymous union:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    enum IpAddrType {
        V4,
        V6
    } type;
    union {
        unsigned V4[4];
        char *V6;
    };
} IpAddr;

void describe_ipaddr(IpAddr addr) {
    switch (addr.type) {
    case V4:
        printf("V4: [%u, %u, %u, %u]\n",
               addr.V4[0],
               addr.V4[1],
               addr.V4[2],
               addr.V4[3]);
        break;
    case V6:
        printf("V6: %s\n", addr.V6);
        break;
    default:
        puts("Unknown IpAddrType");
    }
}

int main(void) {
    IpAddr my_ipaddr = { .type = V6,
                         .V6 = "some_ip_address" };

    describe_ipaddr(my_ipaddr);

    my_ipaddr.type = V4;
    my_ipaddr.V4[0] = 4;
    my_ipaddr.V4[1] = 2;
    my_ipaddr.V4[2] = 0;
    my_ipaddr.V4[3] = 0;

    describe_ipaddr(my_ipaddr);
}
```

Here the `IpAddr` struct contains an enum that acts as a discriminator and an anonymous union that holds the data. Code that uses such tagged unions must be disciplined in maintaining and checking the discriminator to determine the active union member when accessing union members so that undefined behavior is avoided. The `describe_ip_addr` function shows an example of doing this determination in order to describe the contents of an `IpAddr` union.

The above program initializes an `IpAddr` union, prints a description of its contents, changes the contents of the union, and prints a new description:

```
$ ./tagged_union
V6: some_ip_address
V4: [4, 2, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, enums are not objects, like in Java.  You can define an enum in Java an extend the basic enum (which extends Object, or more specificly a base class Enum, that all enums extend)  but in C enums are simple integers (and you can use other values instead the defined ones, as C doesn't implement strong typing, like Java does.)  Imagine in Java extending a base type (a non reference type) like `long` to restrict the value set... you just cannot.  An object oriented language adds support code and the compiler adds code transparently when you e.g. instantiate an object (to transparently call the constructor) which is something that has never been supported in C.